# Liferay 7: Retrieved custom field value using javascript api jsonws return java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, liferay

I'm very new to liferay, I've created a **page custom field** using 'control panel > configuration > custom fields > page'. My goal is to retrieve the value from the page custom field and display the value in my custom portlet. One of the methods I've tried is using ExpandoValue/get-data API from the liferay json web service and this API is generated from localhost:8080/api/jsonws. Below is the generated javascript API:

```js
Liferay.Service(
  '/expandovalue/get-data',
  {
    companyId: themeDisplay.getCompanyId(),
    className: 'com.liferay.portal.model.Page',
    tableName: 'CUSTOM_FIELDS',
    columnNames: 'pageDetail',
    classPK: themeDisplay.getUserId()
  },
  function(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
  }
);
```

However, this api throws me an error: **java.lang.NullPointerException**. I'm thinking that this error occurs due to the permission given to the custom field. So, I've ticked View and Update permissions for Guest. But the issue persists.

My question is what triggered this error and how to fix it and is there any other solution I can use to retrieve the value from the page custom field?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I had misunderstanding in assigning the attributes for the api and here is the new api as suggested by Olaf.

```js
Liferay.Service(
  '/expandovalue/get-data',
  {
    companyId: 20115,
    className: 'com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.Layout',
    tableName: 'CUSTOM_FIELDS',
    columnName: 'details',
    classPK: themeDisplay.getLayoutId()
  },
  function(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
  }
);
```

It works fine. However it only took the default value but not the value assign for that particular pages.

Comment: Hi, do you have a stracktrace? This might help here.

Comment: please provide a stack trace, my experience with NPE´s and accessing Expandos is that the corresponding ExpandoColumn instance does not exist. ... or ... how did you get the classname ?  as Olaf already has recognized .. the Class Page does not exist , therefore  the access towards the ExpandoTable/ ExpandoRow will crash.. if you created the expando in the UI, the column, table and row will already exist.. So it may be only the wrong classname ... have a try and give feedback ..

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves me right, the stock remote API can't be used by unauthenticated users, but requires at least a logged in user (on top of the regular permissions of course).

You can test for this by accessing the API from logged in accounts with the same permissions. If it works there, then this is what you're running into.

However, when I interpret the call in your question correctly, the current user id would be the primary key for the custom field that you're looking at (looking at your `classPK` value). For a custom field on the page, I'd have expected a page id (layoutId in Liferay-API-terms). And while I'm seeing this, I notice `com.liferay.portal.model.Page` in your snippet. I've not seen that class, and pages can rather be found in `com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.Layout` (Assuming [Liferay 7.1](https://docs.liferay.com/dxp/portal/7.1-latest/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/portal/kernel/model/Layout.html))

This makes me wonder what you're trying to achieve here - are you rather looking for a user-specific field (that would then be a custom field on the user) or really a page-specific field? Anyways - as this is an answer, not a comment, it might give enough hints to try out and come closer to a solution.

Comment: Issue solved, I change the classPK value to themeDisplay.getPlid()   :)